# Return null values in conditional join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, entity-attribute-value

I have a `settings` table and a `settings_values` table that cross matches the value for every user. It's important that I return a NULL value in cases where the setting has not been turned on for a user. It's also important that the table is highly efficient as it will be called often.

Ultimately, I have about 50 settings and thousands of users, so every time I run the query I should get 50 result similar to this:

```
setting_id     |     setting_name     |    value     |     user_id
1                    blue                  true            35
2                    red                   NULL            NULL
3                    yellow                false           35
4                    brown                 true            35
5                    black                 NULL            NULL
```

I have a working solution below that's running, but it's creating a bottleneck in my database requests which is strange given that `settings` only has 50 rows and `settings_values` only has about 20,000.

My tables are structured similar to this:

`settings`:

```
setting_id     |    setting_name
```

With setting_id as the only index (Primary Key)

`settings_values`:

```
id      |    setting_id     |    value    |    user_id
```

With `id` being the Primary Key, `setting_id` being a foregin key reference to the previous table, `value` is varchar and `user_id` also has an index on it.

My current working code is the following:

```
SELECT
    s.setting_id,
    s.setting_name,
    sv.value,
    sv.user_id
FROM
    cmssps_settings s
LEFT JOIN cmssps_settings_values sv ON
    s.setting_id = sg.setting_id
    AND sv.user_id = '35';
```

That seems to work OK apart from the bottleneck (I get my 5 rows returned), and I suspect its the JOIN ON AND that's causing the slow down. I've been trying to achieve the same result with a JOIN ON WHERE like this, but I don't get my required NULL results (i.e. it only returns the 3 rows that satisfy the WHERE):

```
    SELECT
        s.setting_id,
        s.setting_name,
        sv.value,
        sv.user_id
    FROM
        cmssps_settings s
    LEFT JOIN cmssps_settings_values sv ON
        s.setting_id = sg.setting_id
        WHERE sv.user_id = '35';
```

When I EXPLAIN both I get this for the former:

```
id  | select_type   | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len   | ref   | rows  | Extra
1   | SIMPLE        | s     | ALL   | [NULL]        | [NULL]| [NULL]    | [NULL]| 49    | [NULL]
1   | SIMPLE        | sv    | ref   | user_id       | branch_id | 5     | const | 24    | Using where
```

When I do it for the latter I get a key value for my first table which I assume indicates that it will excecute faster:

```
id  | select_type   | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len   | ref   | rows  | Extra
1   | SIMPLE        | s     | index | [NULL]        | PRIMARY   | 4     | [NULL]| 49    | [NULL]
1   | SIMPLE        | sv    | ref   | user_id       | branch_id | 5     | const | 24    | Using where
```

I've also attempted nesting the queries and using UNION but that seems like a regression.

Is there anything obvious as to why my initial approach is having such a negative impact on performance?

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN`  approach looks relevant for your use case. For advice on performance, you would need to share your table structures (including indexes) and explain plan for the query.

Comment: Read about Entity-Attribute-Value.  Fix the syntax to be closer to that schema design.  Then rewrite the `SELECT` to fit it.